# Let $f$ be a continuous function on the unit circle. Then there exists a fixed point $p$ such that $f(p) = p$.

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $S = \{p = (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}.$ Let $f : S \to S$ be a continuous function. Then, there always exists $p \in S$ such that $f(p) = p.$

My try:- $S = \{p = (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}.$ is compact but not convex. So, we cannot apply [Brouwer's fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem). So, we can not conclude from here. Can you give any suggesion?

Comment: How about $f(x,y)=(-x,-y)$?

Comment: This is an incorrect assertion. Please reword or correct as appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

The statement isn't right. You may consider rotations as counterexamples.

Comment: Noteworthy that when extended to the unit disk that non-trivial rotations have unique fixed points.